# Program halts until user presses Control+C

Tags: java, windows

I have a java program that does a lot of IO(read files, call other programs, database).

It runs forever on a windows-server from the command line.

Sometimes however, it stops. When this happens, pressing <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> makes the program resume.

What could <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> do that fixes the (hard to reproduce) problem?

Comment: Ctrl+C will terminate the current process in command line. For more info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C

Comment: I know. Thats why I pressed it. But why does it do the opposite?

Comment: Does the application start a child-process? Maybe it is waiting for the child process. When you press CTRL-C maybe the child process is killed, and the application continues to run? (just a wild guess, I have no idea whether CTRL-C will kill the child process and leave the parent untouched)

Comment: Does any other key (F6, Return, Ctrl Z, ...) have same effect or is it only Ctrl C?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I will try that the next time the problem occurs.

Comment: Anyway, the only thing I can imagine that could cause Ctrl-C resume a hanging program, is when this program started a subprocess and waits for the subprocess's end, and the subprocess is actually hanging - what ThomasStets suggested. A Ctrl-C should be handled (and consumed) by the subprocess causing it to end and allowing the caller to resume. @ThomasStets: hard to be sure but I suppose that your comment could be the answer.

Answer (score -2):

If you use

```
 return 0; // or Nothing
```

in the main function and you are sure that your application finish processing call:

```
System.exit(0);//at the end of main
```

Comment: The question is: why does the application *continue* to run after CTRL-C has been pressed?